# как посчитать количество строк в ок 30 таблицах по отдельности

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем! Прошу помочь. Есть около 30 таблиц с названием типа i1, i2, i3 и т.д. Таблицы создаются автоматически поэтому точно не известно сколько именно. Как в них посчитать кол-во строк по отдельности ? Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 0):

цикл? где то так

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=30; $i++) {
 $tbl = "i$i";
 $sql = "select count(*) from $tbl;";
 // выполняем запрос, результат - кол-во строк.
 $count = execsql($sql); // эту функцию придется написать :)
 echo "table $tbl, count = $count";
}
```

если же сами таблицы могут быть с пропусками и их кол-во не известно, то можно вначале выполнить [запрос вида](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html) `show tables;` и получить их все. Более того, этот запрос можно фильтровать - `show tables like i%;` - как обычные select (там также where поддерживается). Теперь, когда список таблиц известен, можно всё прогнать через цикл.

Comment: простите что ввел в заблуждение. Сделал уточнение

Comment: Вместо SHOW TABLES лучше, наверное, делать SELECT к INFORMATION_SCHEMA. А цикл оформить хранимой процедурой и получить уже окончательные данные, а не таскать туда-сюда...

Comment: @Akina не могли бы вы показать на примере?

Comment: SELECT TABLE_NAME AS tbl FROM (SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'data_id' AND TABLE_NAME != 'idare0') `q` ORDER BY TABLE_NAME  сделал так вроде работает но phpmyadmin пишет что есть ошибка

Answer (score 0):

> не могли бы вы показать на примере?

Создание процедуры (один раз, административно):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_counts;

DELIMITER @@;

CREATE PROCEDURE get_counts(IN schemaname CHAR(128), IN pattern CHAR(128))
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tablename CHAR(128);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE table_schema = schemaname
      AND table_name LIKE pattern;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS counts;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE counts (name CHAR(128),cnt bigint) /* ENGINE = Memory */;
OPEN cur1;
REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO tablename;
    SET @strsql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO counts(name, cnt) SELECT \'',
                          tablename, '\', COUNT(*) FROM ', 
                          schemaname, '.', tablename, ';');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @strsql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE cur1;
SELECT * FROM counts;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE counts;
END;
@@;

DELIMITER ;
```

Пример использования:

```
CALL get_counts('mysql','time%');
```